# HibernateException: No session currently bound to execution context

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

I'm trying to create a very basic REST-ish web service with Grails and Postgres. I have the read() & delete() methods working, but I can't get create() to work. Hibernate just gripes, "HibernateException: No session currently bound to execution context." Here's my create method:

```
def create = {
  def member = new Member(params)
  member.save()
  render(status: 201)
}
```

Any advice would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

Since I have EJB3 annotation files as my Grails domain classes, I had to create my own hibernate.cfg.xml for the mappings. I tried changing from

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ManagedSessionContext</property>
```

to

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

They both produced Hibernate session errors. Then I finally found **[this discussion](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-3974)** which suggests you shouldn't have this property in your Hibernate config file at all.